# How to handle Save As dialogue box of excel worksheet in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop

I am trying to write a few lines in the excel sheet and then save using a simple c# program. But every time it shows a dialogue box with "Do you want to save this file?" Yes, No, Cancel options. I want to select yes so that file can be saved with the updated data.

Here is the code:

```
string ID = "123456";

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\Projects\Data\DataSheet.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlWorkSheet = 
(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) xlWorkBook.Worksheets["source"];
//putting the value in excel.
xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2] = ID;

xlApp.Visible = true;
//xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.save();

xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"D:\Projects\Data\DataSheet.xlsx", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

xlWorkBook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
xlApp.Workbooks.Close();
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);

xlApp.Quit();
GC.Collect();
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
```

Its entering the value in the excel sheet but it not saving it. Can someone help to short this issue? or suggest a better approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SaveAs command does not work, but SaveCopyAs does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450447/saveas-command-does-not-work-but-savecopyas-does)

Comment: Just a note, I'd never call `GC.Collect()` unless absolutely necessary, better to prevent imo. as it should collect when it needs resources

Comment: I've added an answer based on _"it saves but still asks me to save"_, then realised that's not your issue. Does `xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"D:Projects\Data\DataSheet.xlsx")` work, without the additional arguments? At want point in your code is the message popping up?

Comment: `D:Projects...` need be `D\:Projects\...`

Comment: @gms0ulman The pop-up is appearing when xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.save(); is executed

Comment: @lomed I have updated it that was just a copy mistake

Answer (score 1):

Try manually setting the `Saved` property to `true`:

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(...);
xlWorkBook.Saved = true;
xlApp.Workbooks.Close()  //not sure if required before: xlWorkBook.Close()
```

---

**Edit**

You could supply arguments to [the `Close()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-close-method-excel). In C#, I believe this would look like this:

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(...);
xlWorkBook.Saved = true;
xlWorkBook.Close(false); //new line
xlApp.Workbooks.Close(); OR xlApp.Workbooks.Close(false);
```

Comment: When I am using this the message is still appearing "A file named DataSheet.xlsx already exists at the location. Do you want to replace it?" with Yes, No and Cancel buttons.
Is there a way you can suggest to select "Yes" or simply do a save and close workbook without these messages appearing. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Ansh AFC - [you can set DisplayAlerts to false](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/application-displayalerts-property-excel)

Comment: Is there a way I can use a save rather than SaveAs?

Comment: Yes; you can do `xlWorkBook.Save()`.

Comment: xlWorkBook.Save(); is also displaying the same message, "A file named DataSheet.xlsx already exists at the location. Do you want to replace it?" with Yes, No and Cancel buttons.

Comment: Have you set DisplayAlerts to false?

Comment: Yes, I have set that but still the pop-up is appearing